# YiiBooster - htmlOptions for items does not work?

Tags: yii, yii-extensions, yii-booster

I'm using http://yii-booster.clevertech.biz/components.html#navbar and I want to generate navbar. I have a problem with that because I have to use `pull-right` css class on one of the items.

Why does `htmlOptions` not work? How to use `pull-right` on item "User"?

```
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbNavbar', array(
    'brand' => CHtml::encode($this->pageTitle),
    'brandUrl' => '#',
    'collapse' => true,
    'type' => 'inverse',
    'items' => array(
        array(
            'class' => 'bootstrap.widgets.TbMenu',
            'items' => array(
                array('label'=>'Home', 'url'=>'#', 'active'=>true),
                array('label'=>'Link', 'url'=>'#'),
                array('label'=>'Link', 'url'=>'#'),
                array('label'=>'User (895)', 'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'pull-right'),
                    'items'=>array(
                        array('label'=>'Support', 'url'=>'#'),
                        array('label'=>'Mailing', 'url'=>'#'),
                        array('label'=>'Sklep', 'url'=>'#'),
                        array('label'=>'Profile', 'url'=>'#'),
                        array('label'=>'Logout', 'url'=>'#'),
                    )
                ),
            )
        )
    )
));
```

Comment: The array you build under 'items' is transformed into <li> elements and each of them is floated left so they are formed into a menu with links in a single row. It doesn't really makes sense to try to float of them right. Or you want to do something else?

Comment: see https://github.com/clevertech/YiiBooster/issues/76

Comment: you have to add '<form class="navbar-search pull-right" method="POST" action="' . $this->createUrl('/search') . '"><input type="text" name="searchtext" class="search-query span2" placeholder="Search Plugin"></form>' at the bottom of your php

Comment: and 'fixed' => TbNavbar::FIXED_TOP,  at the top

Answer (score 3):

Please, try:

```
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbNavbar', array(
    'brand' => CHtml::encode($this->pageTitle),
    'brandUrl' => '#',
    'collapse' => true,
    'type' => 'inverse',
    'items' => array(
        array(
            'class' => 'bootstrap.widgets.TbMenu',
            'items' => array(
                array('label'=>'Home', 'url'=>'#', 'active'=>true),
                array('label'=>'Link', 'url'=>'#'),
                array('label'=>'Link', 'url'=>'#'),
                array('label'=>'User (895)', 'itemOptions'=>array('class'=>'pull-right'),
                    'items'=>array(
                        array('label'=>'Support', 'url'=>'#'),
                        array('label'=>'Mailing', 'url'=>'#'),
                        array('label'=>'Sklep', 'url'=>'#'),
                        array('label'=>'Profile', 'url'=>'#'),
                        array('label'=>'Logout', 'url'=>'#'),
                    )
                ),
            )
        )
    )
));
```

Answer (score 1):

Oh, i see. It should be write in that way:

```
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbNavbar', array(
    'brand' => CHtml::encode($this->pageTitle),
    'brandUrl' => '#',
    'collapse' => true,
    'type' => 'inverse',
    'items' => array(
        array(
            'class' => 'bootstrap.widgets.TbMenu',
            'items' => array(
                array('label'=>'Home', 'url'=>'#', 'active'=>true),
                array('label'=>'Link', 'url'=>'#'),
                array('label'=>'Link', 'url'=>'#'),
            )
        ),
        array(
            'class' => 'bootstrap.widgets.TbMenu',
            'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'pull-right'),
            'items' => array(
                array('label'=>'Name Surname (895)',
                    'items'=>array(
                        array('label'=>'Support', 'url'=>'#'),
                        array('label'=>'Mailing', 'url'=>'#'),
                        array('label'=>'Sklep', 'url'=>'#'),
                        array('label'=>'Profile', 'url'=>'#'),
                        array('label'=>'Logout', 'url'=>'#'),
                    )
                ),
            )
        ),
    )
));
```